# Text-decoration-color not working in python (pyqt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, underline, text-decorations

I am currently working on a little project with Pyqt5, and I'd like to underline a text (which is blue) in red. I have seen many topics that say it is necessary to use text-decoration-color but it is not working for me. Result : I have the text, underlined but underlined in blue and not in red.
If someone had an idea, I would be really grateful.
Here is my code :

```
class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Game")
        self.setGeometry(650,200,700,500)
        self.game()
        self.show()
        self.number = 0
    def game(self):
        title = QLabel("Choose a number", self)
        title.setGeometry(50, 10, 500, 100)
        font = QFont('Comic Sans MS', 17)
        title.setFont(font)
        title.setStyleSheet('QLabel {color: blue ; font-weight : bold ;'\
                'text-decoration : underline; text-decoration-color : red;}')
```

Comment: I don't see any evidence that `text-decoration-color` is a [supported QSS property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties).

Comment: QSS is based specifically on the 2.1 specification (with some custom properties specific to Qt), `text-decoration-color` is part of the [Text Decoration Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-color-property) of CSS3 and therefore not supported. The only way to achieve this is through a QTextDocument (so, no direct QLabel support, but only through QTextEdit and its subclasses or custom painting) and can be set changing the QTextCharFormat using [`setUnderlineColor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcharformat.html#setUnderlineColor).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the answer, I didn't know that.